# Gartner exclusion of elasticsearch and apache solr

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, search-engine

Why is that Gartner excludes Elasticsearch and Apache Solr in magic quadrant?

Aren't they enterprise search engines?

Comment: StackOverflow is a site to help you fixing bugs you're having in your code, or questions on specific piece of code. Such questions tends to bring opinionated answers, and are not desirable.

Answer (score 4):

This [post (opensource Versus Gartner Quadrant)](http://www.informationweek.com/software/information-management/gartner-magic-quadrant-open-source-cloud-disrupt-database-market/d/d-id/1322674)) is very good and shows that the focus of Gartner is mainly on technologies coming out of big blues companies.

Magic  quadrant is to help buy a solution, not to help buy a free solution.
Even if `nosql` is well used, robust, and huge today, Gartner Analyst - [Donald-Feinberg](http://www.gartner.com/analyst/490/Donald-Feinberg) does not think it is a quadrant choice for non webapps.
One exception is Redis.

I have participated in a Gartner event, and could say that it's mainly a vendor place. If you have big revenues, you can appear in the quadrant, otherwise forget it! `Solr`, `ElasticSearch` are great products even if not appearing in the Quadrant ! ;)

Comment: thanks @MayurBuragohain for editing.